# Minimum element in a tree

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, minimum

I want to find the minimum element (at any level) in a non-linear list (edit: a tree), in Lisp. I wrote something like:

```
(defun minimum (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 99999)
    ((atom (car l)) (min (minimum (cdr l)) 99999))
    ((numberp (car l)) (min (car l) (minimum (cdr l))))
    (T (min (minimum (cdr l)) (minimum (Car l))))))
```

But, it's not working (because of that condition for non-numerical atoms, I guess...). Does anyone have, any idea how to fix **this code**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `numberp` case never executes, because the `atom` case is tested first, and numbers are atoms. So every number gets replaced by 99999. Put the `numberp` case first.

The other problem with your code is that it won't find the smallest number if the smallest number in the tree is greater than 99999. To fix it without changing your code too much, you need your own version of `min` that supports a representation of infinity:

```
(defun inf-min (a b)
     (cond ((eq a :infinity) b)
           ((eq b :infinity) a)
           ((< a b) a)
           (t b)))
```

Then, replace `min` with `inf-min` and 99999 with `:infinity`.

Comment: Adding an `(atom l)` case just after the `(null l)` case would allow you to support improper lists.

Answer (score 2):

The use of 99999 is really a hack (not the good kind of hacks), please don't do this. Using `:infinity` is a little better but still, do you want the result to be `:infinity` when giving an empty list?
The `loop` approach is better, but when a list is empty, minimize returns 0, which is often not what we want.

The minimum function is undefined for zero values, so I'll define a `tree-min` function where the result in `nil` when the tree contains no number. Something like this:

```lisp
(defun tree-min (tree)
  (typecase tree
    ;; base case with numbers
    (number tree)

    ;; string are sequences too, but don't iterate over them.
    (string nil) 

    ;; vectors and lists
    (sequence (reduce (lambda (m e)
                        (let ((em (tree-min e)))
                          (or (and m em (min em m)) ; Eminem?
                              em)))
                      tree
                      :initial-value nil))))
```

The function silently skips any non-number element.  Here are some examples:

```
(tree-min #(3 2 nil (2 1 -20) 100 20 ))
=> -20

(tree-min nil)
=> nil

(tree-min '(a 20))
=> 20
```

In practice, you could generalize this function to take a comparison function like [`extremum`](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-utilities/doc/extremum.html) does.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun minimum (tree)
    (loop for item in tree
         if (consp item) minimize (minimum item)
         else if (numberp item) minimize item))
```

Comment: to demystify the loop magic: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html

Comment: That's mostly a matter of style, but you could perform the test inside a single minimize keyword.